# Windows 10 upgrade not received

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I am running Windows 8.1 x64 with all the latest updates from Microsoft. But still when I click on the GWX icon on the system tray it says "We are still evaluating your PC for the update".

People have already received the Windows 10 upgrade. Can anyone tell me why this is taking so long for me? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Re the close vote - I think it ought to stay open, as it is a valid question. The 'opinion' would only be how long it may take to get to the front of the queue - not that not everyone is going to get their upgrade on day one.

Answer (score 7):

Patience…

The servers are trying to roll out to several hundred million users. Your turn will come.

If you really can't wait, you can force the upgrade by getting the [Media Creation Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) & running the install manually from a USB stick.

*From comments…*

Don't try to install by booting from the USB stick, as this would invalidate your free upgrade & you'd need a true Windows 10 key to install.
Without that key, it will reject the install & tell you to run it from inside your current working OS instead - by booting as normal, then running the setup.exe on the stick.
That way, when you get to the install key window, you can skip it & it will authenticate based on your existing install.

The USB stick isn't compulsory - if you have only a single machine to update, you can just run the tool straight from that computer. The USB stick saves multiple machines needing multiple 4GB downloads.
The options are something like [not verbatim]
'Upgrade this machine' & 'Upgrade another machine'
'This' will download & upgrade just that machine, 'another' will allow you to construct a bootable installer on USB, which can be run at boot, or from a running system.

Comment: But don't boot from the stick if you didn't bought a windows 10 key! If want to upgrade your existing 7/8/8.1 key you need to upgrade the existing system and make a clean install afterwards!

Comment: It will actually reject installing from the stick if you don't have a valid Win 10 key & tell you to do it from the existing booted OS instead. When you do that, you can then skip the install key & you get your free upgrade.

Comment: I don't understand, why you need USB stick to run Media Creation Tool? I've run it without any usb stick and it upgraded my W8.1 to W10 in place just fine. Also don't know anything about the keys, it didn't ask me for anything, they just sent me the e-mail saing that I could use MCT if I like.

Comment: If you save it to a stick it saves you having to re-download for every puter in the building. First option you get is 'update this/another machine'. 'another' will let you save it to the stick. I'd actually forgotten about that when answering - but I have quite a few machines to do here.

Comment: It will install from the stick if you skip the key entry, just cant activate it unless you have a purchased key.

Comment: I actually got that far by mistake, when I was working through the possibilities [read.. 'swearing a lot']. The 'skip' button was missing. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said about the media creation tool there are sometimes valid reasons why you have not received the update yet. There are still some known compatibility issues and drivers that are pending fixes and updates, and if the update utility detects that you fit one of those scenarios then it will not offer you the update until they are fixed.

One example can be found [here](http://www.bidnessetc.com/49105-how-to-fix-error-0xc1900101-0x20004-encountered-in-microsoft-windows-10-in/). Once things like this no longer need a workaround then that category of computer will be upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command in the cmd.exe to get the windows 10 download started in the windows-update application:

```
wuauclt.exe /updatenow
```

Answer (score 0):

It will take weeks from now, to everyone get the update. Be patient.

If you don't want to wait you can use [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

Comment: Why is it taking so long ?

Comment: Because of Microsoft. They getting out the updates in waves, latest news says they're already done with nearly 70 million updates. Some hundred millions left. But if you use the link I inserted you can update your system.