# After going back to Win 7 following Win 10 install a long time ago, can I now install Win 10 again and how?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have a boxed copy of Windows 7 Ultimate. A long time ago, I upgraded to Win 10 using one of the upgrade paths from within Windows (can't remember which one exactly). It caused some issues and I reverted to Win 7.

After some time, I decided to give it another go. I ended up using my MSDN license to download an installer and used that to install Win 10.

What I want to do now is to use my own license to reinstall Win 10. As I understand it, this is possible (I have had a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/984761/how-to-reinstall-win-10-update-after-going-back-to-win-7)). My situation is a bit different though because I want to do this as part of a computer upgrade, where I'll be replacing pretty much every component apart from the PSU.

Is it still possible to upgrade even though the hardware configuration is changing? If it is, do I need to first install Win 7 on the new computer, then upgrade to Win 10, and then redo the Win 10 installation from fresh to get a clean install, as implied [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/949755/windows-10-upgrade-not-received)?

Comment: The original Windows 10 install will not survive this major upgrade from the point of view of licensing which is why you need to start over with Windows 7 and then see if you can upgrade

Comment: What is or isn't possible entirely depends if the Windows 7 is a **Retail** or **OEM** license.  Please edit your question to include this vital information required to submit an accurate helpful answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I transfer a Windows 10 licence to my new PC if it was upgraded from a retail licence?](https://superuser.com/questions/980204/can-i-transfer-a-windows-10-licence-to-my-new-pc-if-it-was-upgraded-from-a-retai).  Please see the possible duplicate for more information about installing Windows 10 on a new build with an existing Windows license.  **It is debatable if the upgrade offer (which has expired) applies to a new build in 2019, technically the upgrade offer was for the machine, not the license itself.**

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated the question, though you seem to have seen the relevant update in one of my comments. What I'd be interested to know is, since I've taken the upgrade offer the first time I upgraded from Win 7 to Win 10, would it allow me to install Win 10 using my license. One of your comments here suggests so. I will be sure to read your related answers to other questions later.

Comment: @Moss - Debatable considering the upgrade offer expired 2 years ago.

Comment: @Ramhound Hmmm. My thinking was that I did take up the offer originally, despite later reverting to Win 7. Also your comment Tonny's answer seems to suggest that you agree that I should just be able to bypass all these issues and just install a fresh copy of Win 10 simply by using my original Win 7 key. So I'm a bit confused as to what I can or cannot do.

Comment: You indicated you upgraded your current computer but you want to use it on a new build.  The offer was for the machine not the license

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a OEM or Retail Win7 license you can just do a fresh install of Windows 10 and use your existing Windows 7 key.
The install media can be downloaded via the Microsoft Windows 10 Media Creator utility or straight from MSDN if you have access to MSDN. 
Make sure you use the correct Windows 10 version: Home for a Windows 7 Home edition key. Pro for a Windows 7 Pro or Ultimate.

Comment: This is actually the only 100% accurate answer to this question.

Comment: I have access to MSDN through work. As the new computer will outlive my position at my current employer, I don't want to rely on MSDN.

Comment: @Moss You will only use MSDN to easily get a ISO download of Windows 10. You will be using your own Win7 Ultimate key. The resulting Windows 10 installation has NO dependency on your work.

Comment: After buying the new computer last week and going through the installation over the last weekend, I can confirm that this method worked. I downloaded the Windows 10 Media Creator utility and used the Windows 7 key. The installation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 license is tied to hardware, small hardware changes are no problem but motherboard is. Make your hardware changes and reinstall Windows 10 and activate using your W7 product Key.

Use this W10 tool to get W10 installed and activated>>>>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

If you do not have a valid W7 product key, then you will have to buy a W10 license from Microsoft.

Comment: I do have a fully licensed boxed copy of Win 7 Ultimate so installing it on the new system should not be a problem, I would hope. I can then try the upgrade route that I described and which you also suggested: upgrade to Win 10 and if that works, do a clean install of Win 10 again.

Comment: @Moss - You can transfer a Retail Windows 7 license to your new build in that case.

Comment: It is not longer required to install the previous eligible Windows installation in order to upgrade to Windows 10.  Provided you have a retail license, you can install a supported version of Windows 10 (1511+), and simply use the license key from the eligible version of Windows (8, 8.1, and 7).

Answer (score 0):

You have (or will have) changed enough hardware that Windows 10 will see it as a new machine and not activate.

You can try reinstalling Windows 7 from your original license and activate Windows 7.

Then see if you can still upgrade.  You may need a new Windows 10 license - all you can do is try.

Comment: The author has a Retail Windows 7 Ultimate license so this answer is inaccurate and/or incomplete.  It is no longer required to "install Windows 7" then upgrade that to Windows 10.  **The author could simply install the current version of Windows 10 (1903), when prompted for the license key, they would provide the Windows 7 Retail license key.**  See the other two answers for more information, and/or the dozen answers I have submitted, on how Windows 10 licensing works.